# How to query sum in doctrince 2 with dql?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to convert mysql to dql.
But i don't know how to write.
I read some links from [working-with-objectse](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) and [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) and etc.The more i read, the more i got confused.
So i need some help so that i could understand how dql works.
I have this sql:

```
Select c.value from card c where time like 'xxxx' and type_care not like 'yyyy'
```

I used SQl in doctine and it work. But i would waste if i don;t know dql while using doctine 2.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have assumed your entity field is same as your sql

DQL Query according to your sql :

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c.value')
    ->where('c.time LIKE :paramTime')
    ->setParameter('paramTime', '%'.$yourTimeVariable.'%')
    ->andWhere('c.type_care NOT LIKE :paramTypeCare')
    ->setParameter('paramTypeCare', '%'.$yourTypeCateVariable.'%');

$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Make sure this is a helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me a lot. You cleared  clouds over my head.

Comment: Welcome @Hanata